# How can I create a model's object from a different model with some common properties/attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb

There are two models which has some common properties. Can I use the A's object to create an object of B by passing A as a parameter to new method of B?

For eg
A: height, width, length, name, type, location
B: height, width, length, name, who_bought_it, some_thing_else

It would have been straight forward if B extends A, but not so in this case. So how should I do it? Will mass assignment thing come anywhere here?

(I know, its a bad example!)

Comment: Yes you can do this, but there might be an all together better approach. What are you trying to accomplish? Would it be better to link the objects rather than duplicate the properties? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass Instance A's attributes to Class B

```
ClassB.create(height: instance_a.height, width: instance_a.width)
```